# How the Lead Assignment rules applicable

Tags: limits

I am newbie in Salesforce and my company is switching our CRM to Salesforce. So currently we are learning and doing gap analysis. Previously we had 50+ active lead assignment rules each contains various queries but in salesforce we can have only one rule active at a time. Any suggestion how can I implement this without using process builder & workflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate your 50+ lead assignment rules from your previous CRM as 50+ entries under one lead assignment rule in Salesforce.

In Salesforce a lead assignment rule can have multiple entries for routing the lead. Each entry is composed from one or more criteria. You can think of each entry as a business rule in a traditional sense. The overall lead assignment rule is a collection of these business rules.

Take a look at [Convert and Assign Leads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/admin_intro_opptys_leads/admin_intro_opptys_leads_leads) Trailhead tutorial for an example.

For further reference you can check the [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010397/lead-assignment-rules) here too.

Thanks.